# SELECT COLUMN which has null values (Cassandra 3.11.3)

Tags: cassandra

I have a table (table1) with 14 columns in which 10 columns has data and I need to import data to rest of 4 columns from other table (For now these 4 columns has empty/null value)

My team met has written a code perform import of data from other table but he is facing some issues and he is asking me to give him a select query which will give/display columns which has null/empty dataset (In this example 4 columns which are having null/empty dataset)

I have tried below select query... were I have used distinct query with partition key.

**SELECT distinct host_name from table1 WHERE empty_column = '' ;**

Note: Column - host_name is the primary or partition key and empty_column is the column which does not have any value or null/empty dataset.

Getting error:

**InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="SELECT DISTINCT with WHERE clause only supports restriction by partition key and/or static columns."**

Please help...

Comment: The error indicates you need to use the partition key in the WHERE condition, not the SELECT clause. If you have a limited number of host_name values, and the host_name is the partition key, you can run the query X times, one for each host. However, that does not seem to be what you're trying. In these cases, you may have to write some pro-grammatical code (e.g. in Java) to do the heavy lifting to keep track of your results and print them out.

Comment: Thanks Jim for helping... Can you please help me guide were I can get this information... I'm not a core developer but I can code if I get help.

Comment: I have a variety of code I have written in java for DSE that may work to give you some ideas. If you're using Apache Cassandra, not sure the drivers are compatible, but it will give you an idea of some code and how to connect, query, etc. I'll send it to you via e-mail. I don't use this site too often to know if your e-mail is readily available. If it is, I'll send it to you, otherwise, I'll need to know your e-mail address to send it.

Comment: I was not able to see an e-mail address on this site. If you don't mind publishing it as a follow-up comment, I'll send you some samples (or direct me to where I can find your e-mail address)

Comment: Sorry my bad... PFB, my e-mail address... hpca1078@gmail.com

Comment: Hi Jim, sorry, just to check did you got my mail ID?

Comment: I was looking for it, but did not see it. I am sending one to your e-mail address now.